# wrong WCSessionDelegate callback function called

Tags: watchos-2, watchconnectivity, wcsession

I use the WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage function to send a message from the watch to the iphone, with non nil replyHandler closure

on the iphone,

```
    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject])
```

is called and not the callback that should be called:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
```

and thus i cannot call replyHandler :-(

any idea why?
thanks a lot!

Edit:
code used to make the call:

```
WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(applicationDict, replyHandler: { (reply : [String : AnyObject]) -> Void in
            ...                
        },
        errorHandler: { (er : NSError ) -> Void in
            // Handle error
            print(er.description)
    });
```

Comment: could you post the code where you call sendMessage?

Comment: @ccjensen please see the edit. thanks!

Comment: that looks like a replyHandler to me. Only way I can imagine we'd be able to help further is a more full code example (test project posted to github, or something like that). Only other option I can suggest is to file a bug report with apple and include a sample project